# Specifying method with interface parameter

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, overloading

I spent some time learning how "Event Sourcing" works and how one would implement that in C# and i got stuck at some point.
As it is very difficult to describe my problem without code I'll first give you a simplified version of my code. I removed all the unneeded code and left the relevant parts.

```
public interface IEvent { }
public class UserCreated : IEvent { }
public class UserDeleted : IEvent { }

public interface IEventSourcable
{
    ICollection<IEvent> History { get; }
    void ApplyEvent(IEvent e);
}

public abstract class EntityBase : IEventSourcable
{
    public ICollection<IEvent> History { get; }
    public void ApplyEvent(IEvent e)
    {
        History.Add(e);
    }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public void ApplyEvent(UserCreated e)
    {
        base.ApplyEvent(e)
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to prevent the base method to be used if a matching method is not implemented i. e.

```
User u = new User();
u.ApplyEvent(new UserCreated());
```

should work and call the method in User (which it does) but

```
u.ApplyEvent(new UserDeleted());
```

should not call the base method but give an error at compile time.

I've seen different approaches which would give a runtime error or simply ignore the problem if a matching method is not implemented like

1. Simply override the method and check the type

   ```
   public class User : EntityBase
   {
       public override void ApplyEvent(IEvent e)
       {
           if (e is UserCreated)
               ApplyEvent((UserCreated)e);
           else if (e is UserDeleted)
               ApplyEvent((UserDeleted)e);
           else
               throw new UnknownEventException(); // Or handle it however
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the dynamic operator

   ```
   public abstract class EntityBase : IEventSourcable
   {
       public ICollection<IEvent> History { get; }
       public void ApplyEvent(IEvent e)
       {
           History.Add(e);
           ((dynamic)this).Apply((dynamic)e);
       }
   }

   public class User : EntityBase
   {
       public override void Apply(UserCreated e)
       {
           // do something
       }
   }
   ```

I know I could do it in either one of mentioned ways but I'm more interested in whether what I'm thinking of is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the interface explicitly, which would prevent unwanted event types on a concrete instance:

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEventSourcable
{
    ICollection<IEvent> IEventSourcable.History { get; }

    void IEventSourcable.ApplyEvent(IEvent e)
    {
        // Do the magic
    }

    protected void ApplyEvent(IEvent e)
    {
        (this as IEventSourcable).ApplyEvent(e);
    }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public void ApplyEvent(UserCreated e)
    {
        base.ApplyEvent(e);
    }
}
```

However that wouldn't prevent a consumer from casting to an `IEventSourcable` and adding arbitrary events:

```
IEventSourcable u = new User();
u.ApplyEvent(new UserCreated());
u.ApplyEvent(new UserDeleted());
```

Comment: Even though it's not how I would like to have it it's still a nice approach I didn't think of.
But as you said the consumer can now even cast the object to bypass the mechanism which actually makes it worse.

Comment: It doesn't really make it any worse, the consumer can always case it to the interface if it's implemented by the class. Ultimately, I don't think there's a way to prevent it at compile time.

Comment: That's true but in approach 1 of my post this wouldn't make a difference, isn't it?

Comment: Right, I was concentrating on how you might be able to mitigate the error at compile time.

Comment: I guess what I'd like to achieve is not possible.